# Balancing out created process usage in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

The user launches the program determining how many threads my processes will have like such: `./a.out 2`. He then inputs orders that need to be distributed equally between processes.

So if I have 2 threads per process and 4 orders, I will create 2 processes and distribute my orders as balanced as possible.

Right now I create enough processes and threads but DO NOT balance out order distribution, like such:

```
bool    Reception::createNProcess(const int numPro, const int numOrders)
{
  for (int y = 0; y < numPro; ++y)
    {
      Process           pro; // Encapsulation of process creation (simple fork())
      Thread            t[this->numThreads_]; // Encapsulation of thread manipulation

      // Child process               
      if (pro.getPid() == 0)
        {
           for (int i = 0; i < this->numThreads_; ++i) // Create N Threads
             t[i].startThread((intptr_t)y);         // in newly created process
           for (int i = 0; i < this->numThreads_; ++i)
             t[i].joinThread();
        }
      else if (pro.getPid() < 0)
        {
          std::cerr << "[Error]: Fork failed." << std::endl;
          return (false);
        }
      else // Parent process
        { 
          if (orders.empty())
            haveOrders = false;
          else
            {
              haveOrders = true;
              cv.notify_one();
            }
        }
    }
  return (true);
}
```

How may I make it so that my order distribution is balanced?

Example of the requested behavior:
2 Threads per process, 2 processes and 4 orders.

Process 1 executes order 1; process 2 executes order 2; process 1 executes order 3 and finally, process 2 executes order 4.

I have the following information that may help: number of processes to be created, number of orders inputed by the user, number of threads per process.

Comment: Before forking, take (and remove) `numThreads` orders from the container. If you're the child, distribute those to your threads. If you're the parent, just delete them - they're being handled by the child now.

Comment: If I have understood correctly, this may not be what I meant by balancing. Say you have 2 processes and 4 orders, process 1 will take the first order, process 2 the second and then back to process 1 etc. This may not be the case in your (interesting) idea.

Comment: You'll have to explain better what actual behaviour you need then

Comment: Absolutely, I have added an example. It should simply take the orders and distribute them one by one to the processes in order to balance the execution.